# Graphics Object is currently in use elsewhere (trying to multi-thread drawing primitives)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, graphics

The code I'm going to talk about is a lesser part of a program written just for myself to test a library I'm developing, so I am sure it is not optimal, and I'm not aiming at improving it, because... well, it's not worth it since it's just a personal test tool.

The code is outputting a grayscale image (stored in byte[,]) to a panel.

```
Graphics g = pImage.CreateGraphics()
int left, right, top, bottom;
left = Math.Max(-pImage.Left, 0);
top = Math.Max(-pImage.Top, 0);
right = Math.Min(pContainer.Width - pImage.Left, Layer.Width);
bottom = Math.Min(pContainer.Height - pImage.Top, Layer.Height);
Brush[] currentBrushCatalogue = DimLights ? brushCatalogueDimmed : brushCatalogueNormal;

for (int i = left - left % ImageResolution; i < right - right % ImageResolution; i += ImageResolution)
  for (int j = top - top % ImageResolution; j < bottom - bottom % ImageResolution; j += ImageResolution)
    g.FillRectangle(currentBrushCatalogue[Layer.GetBrightness(i, j)], new Rectangle(i, j, ImageResolution, ImageResolution));
```

Here,

- pImage is the Panel,
- Layer.GetBrightness gets the values from the byte[,] inside Layer
- brushCatalogue is just an array of brushes that translates bytes into Brush objects
- ImageResolution is the way to speed up the process (draw less pixels total for a less detailed image)

Now, I decided to make it parallel. Since you cannot use Graphics object from multiple threads, I decided I'll draw into separate bitmaps and then blend everything together. Thus I made this code:

```
Graphics g = pImage.CreateGraphics()
int left, right, top, bottom;
left = Math.Max(-pImage.Left, 0);
top = Math.Max(-pImage.Top, 0);
right = Math.Min(pContainer.Width - pImage.Left, Layer.Width);
bottom = Math.Min(pContainer.Height - pImage.Top, Layer.Height);
Brush[] currentBrushCatalogue = DimLights ? brushCatalogueDimmed : brushCatalogueNormal;
Bitmap[] bitmaps = new Bitmap[8];

Parallel.For(0, 8, (n) =>
                    {
                        int l = left + (right - left) * n / 8;
                        int r = left + (right - left) * (n+1) / 8;

                        bitmaps[n] = new Bitmap(r - l, bottom - top);
                        Graphics localG = Graphics.FromImage(bitmaps[n]);

                        for (int i = l - l % ImageResolution; i < r - r % ImageResolution; i += ImageResolution)
                            for (int j = top - top % ImageResolution; j < bottom - bottom % ImageResolution; j += ImageResolution)
                                localG.FillRectangle(currentBrushCatalogue[Layer.GetBrightness(i, j)], new Rectangle(i, j, ImageResolution, ImageResolution));

                    }
                    );
for (int n=0;n<8;n++)
  g.DrawImageUnscaled(bitmaps[n],left + (right-left)*n/8,top);
```

Problem is, I'm still getting the error! Where i try to FillRectangle, I get "Object is currently in use elsewhere." error.

Can someone please explain to me what am I doing wrong? I assume that whatever I create inside the function I pass to the Parallel.For is instanced, meaning, each thread has its own copy of l, r, and localG, and each copy works with its own Graphics object. Because obviously otherwise it wouldn't work at all! So why is "Object currently in use elsewhere"? How can localG be currently in use elsewhere if no other thread touches it?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly set up a separate Bitmap/Graphics object for each sub-task, but the Brushes in `currentBrushCatalogue` are still shared.  Brushes are not thread-safe, so you will need to create a deep copy of `currentBrushCatalogue` for each sub-task:

```
Parallel.For(0, 8, (n) =>
{
    var palette = currentBrushCatalogue.Select( x => x.Clone() ).Cast<Brush>().ToArray();

    // use palette instead of currentBrushCatalogue below

    int l = left + (right - left) * n / 8;
    int r = left + (right - left) * (n+1) / 8;

    // ...
```

Comment: Agreed.  The Brushes class is notable, it uses thread-local storage to return brushes that are safe to use from multiple threads.

Comment: @HansPassant, do you have a reference for that?  I thought that I had problems in the past using `Brushes`/`Pens` values during background rendering.

Comment: Just look at the Reference Source or use a decompiler.

Comment: Interesting. I will try this and report back

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Wierd thing is - creating new bitmaps every time turned out to be faster than creating them only on Resize event of the panel...